# Empty csv in jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, sed, devops

I need to write a shell script to extract the 'select' statements from an uploaded sql file( uploaded as a jenkins parameter) and get the output to a csv file. This is the execute shell script which I wrote for that. Uploaing file location is given as "var/lib/jenkins/workspace/staging_selectqueries_alp".But I get empty csv as the output.Can someone help me on that?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "\n\n####### Running the select queries###### \n"
test= ls -t -1 | sed '1q'
dbname=$Database
mysql -u root -p$PASS -h alp-uk-stg.cmw7mobxvnye.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com $dbname 
sed '/;/G' $test | grep "SELECT" | sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n/~/g;ta' | tr "~" "\n"|sed "s/\"/\"\"/g;s/'/\'/;s/\t/\",\"/g;s/^/\"/;s/$/\"/;s/\n//g">output.csv
```

Comment: Please share content of `$test ` file. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It contains just a select query. [ select * FROM tblsubscription].The uploading location is given as var/lib/jenkins/workspace/staging_selectqueries_alp